# Suppose, for some θ ∈ [0, π/2 ], cos 3θ/cos θ = 1/3 . Then (cot 3θ) tan θ equals-

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose, for some θ ∈ [0,π/2], cos3θ/cos θ = 1/3 . Then (cot3θ)tanθ equals-

Options:

(A) 1/2

(B) 1/3

(C) 1/8

(D) 1/7

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We need to find $\displaystyle \cot(3x)\tan(x) = \frac{\cos(3x)}{\sin(3x)}\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{\cos(3x)}{\cos(x)}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(3x)}$.

Since we know $\displaystyle \frac{\cos(3x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{1}{3}$ we need to find $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(3x)}$.

There are two identities $\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3(x) - 3\cos(x)$ and $\sin(3x) = 3\sin(x) - 4\sin^3(x)$. We will use these in the following section.

$\displaystyle \frac{\cos(3x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{4\cos^3(x) - 3\cos(x)}{\cos(x)} = 4\cos^2(x) - 3 = \frac{1}{3}$.

Thus we can conclude that $\displaystyle \cos^2(x) = \frac{5}{6} \implies 1 - \cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{6} = \sin^2(x)$.

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(3x)} = \frac{\sin(x)}{3\sin(x) - 4\sin^3(x)} = \frac{1}{3-4\sin^2(x)} = \frac{1}{3-4(\frac{1}{6})} = \frac{3}{7}$.

Therefore $\displaystyle \cot(3x)\tan(x) = \frac{\cos(3x)}{\cos(x)}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(3x)} = \frac{1}{3}\times\frac{3}{7} = \frac{1}{7}$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.